# Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Tags: maven, plugins, download, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to move my POM.XML into linux build environment, maven-dependency-plugin is not getting downloaded. I checked proxy settings too. Except this plugin, other plugins, dependencies are resolved without any issues. I am using Maven 2.2.1

below is the pom.xml and the Error Message.

**Can anyone help me resolve this problem?**

```
POM.XML:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>NBC</groupId>
    <artifactId>CIR</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>cirjob-batch</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>JIRA</system>
        <url>http://usaoaapld311lb.nbcuni.ge.com:8080</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>Bamboo</system>
        <!--<url>http://usaoaapwd189:8085</url> -->
        <url>http://usaoaapld311la.nbcuni.ge.com:8085</url>
    </ciManagement>
    <scm>
        <url>svn://usaoaapld311lb.nbcuni.ge.com:3690/CIR</url>
    </scm>
    <!-- Fisheye/Crucible http://usaoaapwd189:8060 -->

    <organization>
        <name>NBC</name>
        <url>NBC.COM</url>
    </organization>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Crystal Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
            <artifactId>CrystalReportsRuntime</artifactId>
            <version>${com.crystaldecisions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
            <artifactId>CrystalCommon2</artifactId>
            <version>${com.crystaldecisions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
            <artifactId>DatabaseConnectors</artifactId>
            <version>${com.crystaldecisions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
            <artifactId>QueryBuilder</artifactId>
            <version>${com.crystaldecisions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jrcerom</artifactId>
            <version>${com.crystaldecisions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycodeDecoder</artifactId>
            <version>${com.crystaldecisions.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
            <version>${com.businessobjects.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.businessobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDBInterface</artifactId>
            <version>${com.businessobjects.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azalea</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.azalea.ufl.barcode</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Old Servlets -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat not having jstl lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId> 
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> 
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId> <artifactId>quartz</artifactId> <version>1.6.0</version> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId> <artifactId>quartz</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.5</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                    <groupId>freemarker</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jbosscache</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- ActiveMQ <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId> <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId> 
            <version>${org.apache.activemq.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- <org.apache.activemq.version>5.4.3</org.apache.activemq.version> -->

        <!-- JSON this should be replaced by Gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.seleniumhq.selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>${org.seleniumhq.selenium.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- <exclusion> <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
                    </exclusion> -->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>conf\batch\dev</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target\classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>cfg\batch\dev</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/reportEngine/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/controller/reporting/ReportEngineController.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/service/ReportEngineService.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <archive>
                        <!-- <manifest> <mainClass>main.java.batch.com.ge.nbcuni.job.ReportJobBatch</mainClass> 
                            </manifest> -->
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>3.5.4-Final</org.hibernate.version>
        <org.seleniumhq.selenium.version>2.12.0</org.seleniumhq.selenium.version>
        <com.crystaldecisions.version>12.2.2</com.crystaldecisions.version>
        <com.businessobjects.version>12.2.2</com.businessobjects.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
    </modules>

</project>



ERROR:

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-2.0.pom
19-Nov-2012 11:10:09    [INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:09    Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-2.0.pom
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0' from repository Sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases): Error transferring file: oss.sonatype.org
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-2.0.pom
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0' from repository JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories): Error transferring file: repository.jboss.org
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2//org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-2.0.pom
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0' in repository Java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.0/maven-dependency-plugin-2.0.pom
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    from the specified remote repositories:
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10     for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] Trace
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin': POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    from the specified remote repositories:
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10     for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1557)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.bindPluginToLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1503)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.constructLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1282)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:534)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin': POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    from the specified remote repositories:
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10     for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:293)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:205)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:184)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultPluginManager.java:1642)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            ... 18 more
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    from the specified remote repositories:
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10     for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:605)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:277)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            ... 22 more
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    from the specified remote repositories:
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-releases),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      JBoss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories),
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10      Java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:228)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            ... 24 more
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:404)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10            ... 26 more
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 19 11:10:10 EST 2012
19-Nov-2012 11:10:10    [INFO] Final Memory: 4M/57M
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sitting behind a proxy (I just tested it via browser which works perfect)? Furthermore i would strongly recomment to start using a repository manager. Do you have really good reasons to move away from Maven conventions (src/main/java etc.?). If you need excludes in maven-jar-plugin this is an indicator having several separate maven modules instead of a single module. What is the idea of maven-dependency-plugin to copy artifacts to an different folder? Why not using Maven 3.0.X instead of 2.2.1 ? BTW: Spring framework is available in Maven Central so no need to separately giving a repository. Apart from that the given URL to SpringSource repository is the staging repository for SpringSource to Maven Central.

Comment: 1. I am trying to build a java batch program from a web project. the standalone java program will be later given to scheduling to team to configure & run.
2. I have created a separate directory structure for jar (src/main/java) but i want my dependent services from the web project needs to be packed inside a jar as well. That's why i specified the source location as src

3. I want the classpath libraries to be deployed into a batch server, so that the batch server will hold the latest libraries after each deployment. thats why i created target/lib folder. bamboo will do the deployment.

Comment: Even when i tested it from the browser, it works perfectly! From my windows development machine, this POM works just fine.